# How can I change the bounderies of the following sum

Tags: summation, summation-method

i want to change the lower bound of the summation with $k=0$.
$$\sum_{k=2}^{r+s-1} { \{ \begin{pmatrix} k-1\\r-1\\ \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix} k-1\\s-1\\ \end{pmatrix} \} } H(k,r+s-k) $$

In here, I want to take the sum from $k=0$.
$$\sum_{k=2-\color{red}{2}}^{r+s-1-\color{red}{2}} $$.

Then, how can I change the middle part?

I know to change the bounderies in a summation like below
$$\sum_{i=x}^{y} f(i)=\sum_{i=x-a}^{y-a} f(i+a) $$.

And also there is another property 
$$\sum_{i=x}^{y} f(i,y)=\sum_{i=x+t}^{y+t} f(i-t,y-2t) $$.

But sometimes this doesn't work. Could you please explain this also?

Comment: You can get $\binom{n}k$ with `\binom{n}{k}`. Also, the curly braces can be autosized by using `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to make a formal substitution $\ell=k-2$, so that $k=\ell+2$. Then

$$\sum_{k=2}^{r+s-1}\left(\binom{k-1}{r-1}+\binom{k-1}{s-1}\right)H(k,r+s-k)$$

automatically becomes

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^{r+s-3}\left(\binom{\ell+1}{r-1}+\binom{\ell+1}{s-1}\right)H(\ell+2,r+s-\ell-2)\;.$$

If you wish, you can now simply rename $\ell$ back to $k$ to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{r+s-3}\left(\binom{k+1}{r-1}+\binom{k+1}{s-1}\right)H(k+2,r+s-k-2)\;.$$

As a quick partial check, note that the upper number of the binomial coefficients is still $1$ less than the first argument of $H$, as it should be, and the two arguments of $H$ still sum to $r+s$, as they should.

**Added to cover the addition to the question:** Suppose that we start with the summation

$$\sum_{i=x}^yf(i,y)$$

and let $j=i+t$, so that $i=j-t$. Making the substitution, we see that

$$\sum_{i=x}^yf(i,y)=\sum_{j=x+t}^{y+t}f(j-t,y)\;,$$

and we can then rename $j$ back to $i$ to find that

$$\sum_{i=x}^yf(i,y)=\sum_{i=x+t}^{y+t}f(i-t,y)\;.$$

There is no change in the second argument of $f$, because $y$ is a constant: it does not depend in any way on the index variable. The range of values of the index variable depends on $y$, but that’s a different thing altogether. The formula

$$\sum_{i=x}^{y} f(i,y)=\sum_{i=x+t}^{y+t} f(i-t,y-2t)$$

is simply wrong.

Comment: Is that correct? Because in the upper boundary there is $r+s-1$. $s$ and $r$ are in the function. You just change the value of $k$. Don't we have to change their values also?

Comment: @Oily: You definitely do *not* want to change $r$ and $s$: they are constants that have nothing to do with the index of summation.

Comment: Thanks! I have mentioned a property of summation. Could you please explain it?

Comment: @Oily: Are you sure that you wrote what you intended to write? As it stands, the new one doesn’t make sense: on the left $f$ is a function of one variable, and on the right it’s a function of two variables.

Comment: I saw it somewhere on Wikipedia. Sorry! There was a mistake. I corrected it

Comment: @Oily: I’ve added a discussion of the new formula.

Comment: @Oily: You're welcome!